# set an additional class to a dynamically created div

Tags: php, html

```
function givemetitles($table){
    global $db;
    $titles = '';
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT id, title FROM " . $table . " ORDER BY title ASC");
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $titles.= 
                  "<div data-id=" . $row['id'] . 
                  " class='linkl'>" . $row['title'] . "</div>\n"; 
     }
     echo $titles;
}
```

This writes the divs with `linkl` class successfully.

I need the first div to also contain the class `linklactive` - if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach is to set the class, and then clear it:

```
function givemetitles($table){
    global $db;
    $titles = '';
    // set $first_class to the class you want for the first record
    $first_class = ' linklactive';
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT id, title FROM " . $table . " ORDER BY title ASC");
    while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) { 
        // include $first_class in the $title value
        // tweaked to use string interpolation
        // Switched to PHP_EOL instead of \n
        $titles.= "<div data-id='{$row['id']}' class='linkl{$first_class}'>{$row['title']}</div>" . PHP_EOL;
        // reset $first_class to be empty string
        $first_class = ''; 
    }

    echo $titles;    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just count how many times you have looped, in the first run, you add that class...

```
function givemetitles($table,$row_active = 0){

    global $db;
    $titles = '';
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT id, title FROM " . $table . " ORDER BY title ASC");
    $count = 0;
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        if($count == $row_active){
            $titles.="<div data-id=" . $row['id'] . " class='linkl linklactive'>" . $row['title'] . "</div>\n";
        }else{
            $titles.="<div data-id=" . $row['id'] . " class='linkl'>" . $row['title'] . "</div>\n";
        } 
        $count++;
    }
    echo $titles;

}
```

Pretty? No not really, but it does the job.

That said, in this case the [cale_b answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41767669/5120280) is more on point and *"prettier"*. I am keeping this answer as you can define which row gets the class.

Comment: Also, the reason I encouraged you to un-delete this answer is because when future visitors find this question and answer, it's very helpful to have a "variety" of answers with different approaches.  I for one have learned TONS from SO just by seeing the variety of approaches to different problems!